# xml Element Tree : fail to get expected output

Tags: xml, parsing, python-2.7, elementtree

I am using xml.ElementTree to loop through a python list and write it to an xml file in a tree structure. Here is the following code and follows the desired output. Can any1 please help me!!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
sample = ['germany','India','USA','srilanka']

root = ET.Element("root")
data = ET.SubElement(root, "data")
title = ET.SubElement(data, "country")
for a in sample:
   title.text = a
   data.append('title')

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("page.xml")
```

Current output

```
- <root>
      <data>
          <country>srilanka</country> 
          <country>srilanka</country> 
          <country>srilanka</country> 
          <country>srilanka</country> 
          <country>srilanka</country> 
      </data>
  </root>

Expected output
  <root>
      <data>
          <country>germany</country> 
          <country>india</country> 
          <country>usa</country> 
          <country>srilanka</country> 
      </data>
  </root>
```

I need the output in this fashion...help me !!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you append always the same element, which gets modified to reflect the final value. Note, that append works with a reference, not with a snapshot copy as you seem to expect. Easiest fix is, to create a new subelement instance for each country.